# Proper way to perform GET API Call with API key in header?

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I've never really attempted to try and write my own code that calls an API. I have some Python code that I created after discovering Python Requests library.

However, I can't get past this "authentication failed" error message.

The API key I have acquired is from https://fortnitetracker.com/site-api

The code I am using is as follows:

```
import requests
url = 'https://api.fortnitetracker.com/v1/profile/pc/ninja'
headers = {"TRN-Api-Key": "MY_KEY"}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

After asking for the r.status_code I get a 403 Forbidden. When I ask for r.text I get

> u'{"message":"Invalid authentication credentials"}\n'

On the API page,all they say is to pass the API key in the request headers using a GET method.

I even tried passing my credentials I used to register on the site using

```
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers,auth=('User', 'Pass'))
```

Still got the same invalid authentcation credentials error.

Is what I am doing correct? What am I missing?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Where do you get the `TRN-Api-Key` header from? Do you have a link to their docs?

Comment: To make use of our APIs we require you to use an API Key. To use the API key you need to pass it along as a header with your requests.

TRN-Api-Key: REDACTED

Answer (score 2):

If you are calling an API you need to send post :

r = requests.post(url, headers=headers)

Comment: u'{"message":"no API found with those values"}\n'

Comment: Why do you think a post would be any different? Posting it done if you want to save values at their end. The OP also specifies that the API party says that a GET is required. And since he's trying to fetch data, I'd say that using a GET is correct :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't have to supply the API key something like this?

```
{'Auth': 'Token my_key'}
```

That's how most API's do it, but I can't find any reference to their API docs anywhere.

Comment: Gave your suggestion a go. u'{"message":"No API key found in request"}\n' - I realize they don't really provide any API documentation. That's why I am wondering if its really on my end that I am doing something wrong

Comment: If it's easier you can also try `curl`ing the url with a header like this: `curl --header "Auth: Token my_token" my_url`

Comment: Hm, so it looks like the header you're using is the correct one. So it really looks like you have invalid credentials. Can you try regenerating the key?

Comment: No I cannot. The site doesn't give me the option to generate a new key sadly.

Comment: In that case I'd maybe suggest contacting their support department or trying to get a different key with a different account (maybe just try creating an account with 10 minute mail to get a new API key).