# How to fix a "Invalid authentication credentials" error when accessing an API

Tags: python, api, post, get, python-requests

I am trying to access the fortnite tracker api (https://fortnitetracker.com/site-api) to download some data and perform some analysis.

I have a key but each time I try to pass it as a header (per the website above), I keep receiving a "Invalid authentication credentials" error. I have tried passing in my username and password, but that has not worked either.

```
import requests
session = requests.session()
api_key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
make_link = lambda player,platform: 'https://api.fortnitetracker.com/v1/profile/{}/{}'.format(platform,player) #this just makes the link for the proper player
sample_platform, sample_player = 'pc','Ninja'
sample_link = make_link(sample_epic_name,sample_platform)
headers = {'TRN-Api-Key': api_key} #this is the name of the api-key per the link
session.get(sample_link, headers = headers).content #this returns a message that specifies my original error: "Invalid authentication credentials"
```

I want to just be able to overcome the access issue of this API so that I can use it. Please let me know if I need to make any changes. I found the link listed above to be helpful but not for novice API users such as myself. Thank you!

Comment: First, when did you ask for this API key ? It might just be a problem of replication on their servers if you did it recently.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49749498/proper-way-to-perform-get-api-call-with-api-key-in-header this guy had the same exact problem with the very same API, and so do I (I tried reproducing your problem), unfortunately he didn't seem to get an answer. I suggest, if you can, that you wait until tomorrow to verify it does not come from their side.

Comment: @v-déhaye I requested it only once around a few days ago. My code did not work then and does not work now either. The only logical thing that occurs to me is possibly adding in more headers? I wish they had better documentation.. Thank you for your help

Comment: I don't think it is the solution, because the error explicitly says that your API key is not a valid one. If you remove it from the headers, it returns a different error message, which says the request lacks the key. You are right about the documentation which is a bit light though. You should try to contact them, and if they help you fixing this issue, please post the solution here and mark it as accepted so that the community can make benefit of it :)

Comment: @v-déhaye Thank you so much for your help. They really discourage asking for help, though unsure why. Will update accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experienced the same problem and contacted their support a few days ago. This is what they answered yesterday.

> We had a issue in our system that was not activating api keys correctly, so you may have been getting 403 or 401 errors.  This has been corrected.

I have tried it out again using `curl --header "TRN-Api-Key: <my_key>" https://api.fortnitetracker.com/v1/store` and it's now working for me.